# How do you compare two alphanumeric Strings with the conditions described below?

Tags: swift, algorithm

I'll try to define the problem in words, but this is easier explained with the use of the example test cases.

```
"b" > "a"
"3" > "1"
"ac" > "ab"
"32" > "25"
"abcd1" > "abc2"
"abc123a" > "abc2a"
"abc123a" < "abc1234a"
"abc123" < "abc123a"
"abc12a49" > "abc12a39"
"123ab3" = "123ab3"
"ab12" > "12ab"
"ab12" > "345"
```

I need to compare alphanumeric strings. It is trivial when there are only numbers or only characters in the string, but when they are combined, it becomes more complicated. Basically I need to compare the number groups as one whole number instead of individual numbers, if I make sense.

The following is what I tried. It is a brute force approach to split the string into groups of alphabets and numbers.
I think this works but it is not very performant nor elegant. Is there a better way to achieve this. I'm pretty much dumping all the dependent extensions and methods needed for this to run on the playground, so very sorry for the lack of formatting.

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    
    mutating func removeFirstSafe() -> Element? {
        
        guard !isEmpty else { return nil }
        return removeFirst()
    }
}

extension String {
    
    func split(grouping charSets: [[Character]]) -> [(CharacterType, String)] {
        
        var subStrings = [(CharacterType, String)]()
        
        var copy = self
        copy.__split(grouping: charSets, groupedSubstrings: &subStrings)
        
        return subStrings
    }
    
    mutating func __split(grouping charSets: [[Character]], groupedSubstrings: inout [(CharacterType, String)]) {
        
        guard let previousCharacter: Character = removeFirstSafe() else {
            return
        }
        var groupedSubString = String(previousCharacter)
        
        let prevCharSetGroup: CharacterType = charSets.indexOfCharSetGroupContainingCharacter(previousCharacter)

        while let currentCharacter = first, charSets.indexOfCharSetGroupContainingCharacter(currentCharacter) == prevCharSetGroup {
            
            groupedSubString.append(currentCharacter)
            removeFirst()
        }
        
        groupedSubstrings.append((prevCharSetGroup, groupedSubString))
        __split(grouping: charSets, groupedSubstrings: &groupedSubstrings)
    }
}

enum CharacterType: Int, Comparable {
    
    case alphabet = 1
    case number = 0
    case unknown = -1
    
    static func < (lhs: CharacterType, rhs: CharacterType) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

extension Array where Element == [Character] {
    
    func indexOfCharSetGroupContainingCharacter(_ char: Character) -> CharacterType {
        
        for (index, group) in self.enumerated() {
            
            if group.contains(char) { return CharacterType(rawValue: index) ?? .unknown }
        }
        return .unknown
    }
}

extension Collection {

    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

struct AlphanumericString {
    var string: String
}

func <(lhs: (CharacterType, String), rhs: (CharacterType, String)) -> Bool {
    
    if lhs.0 > rhs.0 { return false }
    else if lhs.0 < rhs.0 { return true }
    else {
        if lhs.0 == .alphabet || lhs.0 == .unknown { return lhs.1 < rhs.1 }
        else { return (Int(lhs.1) ?? 0) < (Int(rhs.1) ?? 0) }
    }
}

extension AlphanumericString: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: AlphanumericString, rhs: AlphanumericString) -> Bool {
        
        if lhs.string == rhs.string { return false }
        
        let lhsGrouped = lhs.string.split(grouping: [Array("12345"), Array("abcde")])
        let rhsGrouped = rhs.string.split(grouping: [Array("12345"), Array("abcde")])
        
        for idx in lhsGrouped.indices {
            
            let lhsItem = lhsGrouped[idx]
            guard let rhsItem = rhsGrouped[safe: idx] else { return false }
            
            if lhsItem < rhsItem { return true }
            else if rhsItem < lhsItem { return false }
        }
        
        return true
    }
}

print(AlphanumericString(string: "abcd1") < AlphanumericString(string: "abc2"))
```

Comment: Are the strings you compare always so equal in format, that is do they always have the same number and order of letter and digit groups?

Comment: No, they can have different number of groups and the group in the same position can be different. For example, "ab12" > "12ab" and "ab12" > "345" should be true

Comment: Why? There is nothing in your question explaining why those two examples should be true.  Also I think your question should be more focused, asking if there is a better way is very vague.

Comment: _"ab12" > "12ab"_. Can you explain _why_ is `"ab" > "12"`?

Comment: Maybe I'll put it this way. I felt like I'm checking many edge cases and adding too many conditions. By better way I mean, a more generalised/ elegant solution or algorithm without so many if statements or loops. I'm not too good with english, sorry.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Character group ranks higher than number for my use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is trivial

It is indeed, because there is an API: [`localizedStandardCompare(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409742-localizedstandardcompare)

The description is ***Compares strings as sorted by the Finder.***

```
func numericCompare(lhs: String, rhs: String, mode: ComparisonResult) -> Bool {
   lhs.localizedStandardCompare(rhs) == mode
}

numericCompare(lhs: "b" ,rhs: "a", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "3" ,rhs: "1", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "ac" ,rhs: "ab", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "32" ,rhs: "25", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "abcd1" ,rhs: "abc2", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "abc123a" ,rhs: "abc2a", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "abc123a" ,rhs: "abc1234a", mode: .orderedAscending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "abc123" ,rhs: "abc123a", mode: .orderedAscending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "abc12a49" ,rhs: "abc12a39", mode: .orderedDescending) // true
numericCompare(lhs: "123ab3" ,rhs: "123ab3", mode: .orderedSame) // true
```

An alternative is `lhs.compare(rhs, options: .numeric)` which does the same

Comment: wow, this looks promising. Let me try this.

Comment: @MartinR the answer is the same, but my question is different maybe? The one there has a pretty standard format to sort. My use case could have any combination of alphabets and numbers

Comment: @MartinR I have a solution that would work correctly for the question linked, namely 1. drop all non numeric characters, 2. convert to integer, 3. compare and sort. Which would not work here. Obviously, this is for the sake of argument, but an argument can be made. However I must admit that I had looked at similar questions and answers and thought those that would not work for my use case that I considered was very specific. And I admit I was wrong.